# How to wax a bow string

Tags: gear-care, archery

I've heard that I've to wax my bowstring. I'm a little bit lost on how to do so.

I've a Dacron Flemish string on a hunting recurve.

[image]

Can anyone lead the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, yes, you should absolutely wax your bow string. Especially if you've this kind of setup. 
The good news is, that it's extremely easy.

### Get a bow wax

Purchase an appropriated wax from your local bow-dealer. Just buy a "real" bow-wax. There are a lot of resources on the www which suggest different kinds of other waxes. However, this is often a compromise somehow.

However, what I want to say is that a bow wax isn't really expensive and therefore no need to compromise.

[image]

### Put the wax on the string

A wax is often kind of like a glue stick. Take off the cap and circle the stick on your string (your bow has to be strung). Do this four times: the upper side, the lower side, the right side and of course the left side. Leave out the "middle" around your nock point.

### Rub the string with your fingers

Now put the string between your thumb and your index finger. Start to rub really, really intensively. You'll recognize that the string gets hot. That's good, cause the wax has to get fluid and so into your string.

### Clean the string with a cloth

Get a cloth and rub it gently around your string so that the excessed wax is rubbed away. You shouldn't see any surplussed material at the end.

### Further information

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dQt-w2zkAw

Answer (score 5):

Just another option to OddDeer. I was taught to use a block of beeswax. Make sure the string is dry and rub the block up and down the string while the bow is strung. Very cost effective, one block lasted me years, and works as well as bow wax.

As a side note always wax around the nock point otherwise you will have a weak point over time.